# When using multiple continuous instruments do I get a weighted Local Average Treatment Effect?

Tags: instrumental-variables

I have the following model:

$y_i = \alpha + \beta d_i + g(x_i)+e_i$

Since I have reason to believe that $d_i$ is endogenous, I am using 3 plausibly exogenous variables ($z_1,z_2,z_3$) to instrument it. Both $d_i$ and my instruments are continuous variables. My first stage regression takes the form

$d_i = \gamma+\gamma_1 z_1+\gamma_2  z_2+ \gamma_3 z_3+f(x_i) + u_i$

**Question1**: What is the interpretation of Local Average Treatment effect when there is one continuous instrument (say just $z_1$)? Is it the treatment effect on all $i$'s whose $d_i$ changes due to a change in $z_1$? Can I interpret that as the average treatment effect of $d_i$ over the support of $z_1$?

**Question 2**: When I have multiple instuments, like in my case, does the LATE become a weighted average of LATEs from each instrument?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question 1: when there's only 1 continuous instrument $z_1$ and no $x$, the 2SLS estimator yields a weighted average of individual treatment effects $\beta_i$ (assuming treatment effect heterogeneity), where the weights are the individual first-stage coefficient $\gamma_{1,i}$.

To see why this is the case, see [Nick Huntington-Klein (2020)](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/jci-2020-0011/html) section 2.1 and appendix 1 for a
simple illustration.

To answer your question 2: yes but conditionally. [Imbens and Angrist (1994)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2951620) (Theorem 2) show that when treatment is binary and instrument $Z$ is discrete, then the IV estimator yields a convex combination of LATEs at each discrete level of $Z$, under regularity conditions. Furthermore, [Mogstad, Torgovitsky, and Walters (2021)](https://www.aeaweb.org/articles?id=10.1257/aer.20190221) show that in presence of multiple instruments, 2SLS estimator also yields a weighted average of LATEs, under a mild, testable "partial monotonicity" assumption.

Comment: Please provide a full reference for the paper in case the link dies in the future. Thx